# Some problem using two-way data binding between parent and child components

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use two-way data binding between the parent and child components. My child component is phoneInput that accepts a phone number, formats it and passes it to the parent using two-way data binding. For most part, the scheme is working.

Parent Component:

```
 <phoneInput v-model="phone"   :error="phoneError"/> {{ phone }}
```

The phoneInput component:

```
<script>
    import { formatPhoneNumber } from "./common_functions.js";

export default {
    props: ["modelValue", "error"],
    emits: ["update:modelValue"],

watch: {
    error: function (val) {
        this.passedPhoneError = val;
        this.inputEntered = false;
    },
},

data() {
    return {
        passedPhoneError: null,
        inputEntered: null,
    };
},

computed: {
    value: {
        get() {
            return this.modelValue;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.inputEntered = true;
            const newval = formatPhoneNumber(value);  // remove all non numeric charactes and format as '647-666-8765'
            console.log(newval);
            this.$emit("update:modelValue", newval);
        },
    },

    phoneError() {
        return this.passedPhoneError  && !this.inputEntered;
    },
},


};
</script>

<template>
    <v-text-field label="Phone*" :error="phoneError" v-model="value" />
</template>
```

The `formatPhoneNumber()` function removes all non-numeric characters and returns a string in the '999-999-9999' or '1-999-999-9999' format. As long as I enter only numeric data, everything works fine. However, when I enter non numeric input, e.g. 64786A, while formatPhoneNumber() returns the correct value which gets passed to the parent, the child continues to display phone number, including the non numeric character, e.g. `647-86A`.

So, my question is, how can I update the value being displayed in the child component with the formatted phone number returned by formatPhoneNumber(), which is available in `newval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an invalid character is entered, the parent still only receives the same valid value it had before.  Since there is no change in the Parent, it doesn't take any action to send that value back down to the Child.  Not having any updated `modelValue`, the computed getter doesn't run and v-text-field `value` doesn't update either.

I suggest adding additional validation on the text field to *prevent* non-numeric characters, instead of just replacing them.  This way you don't have to worry about sending or receiving an updated value from the parent for non-numeric characters. The text field itself will take care of it.

```html
  <v-text-field v-model="value" label="Phone*" @keypress="validate($event)" />
```

```js
validate(e) {
  const char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
  if (/\D/g.test(char)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```